# Epublib crashing In Android

Tags: java, android, parsing, epub, epublib

I'm trying to use this [Epub Library](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib) in Android to parse an Epub file, but whenever I try to use it, the app just force closes.

```
EpubReader epubReader = new EpubReader();
```

Even this line makes it crash. The debugger is telling me it is caused by

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitilizerError

I have no idea what to do. As far as I can tell, the library only uses Java, so I don't think it could be that it is not supported.

Could anyone help me on this? Or if anyone could recommend another way to parse an Epub on Android I would be just as grateful.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Epublib does run on Android now, see http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android

Answer (score 2):

Right now epublib does not run on Android. u can check this url http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android. thx